# Why column with null value come before column with values when you order by a timestamp column in oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, oracle9i

I've got a strange behaviour with an Oracle 9i database. If i make a query like this:

```
 select * from table order by dp_dt_timestamp DESC;
```

where dp_dt_timestamp  is a timestamp column, rows which have null  values in the column dp_dt_timestamp come before those that have a value.

How can i put the null values as the last values and still have the timestamps ordered Descending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order by dp_dt_timestamp DESC NULLS LAST`

By default NULLs come last when sorting ASC and first when sorting DESC.